# PHP check images before update

Tags: php, image, validation, upload

I'm looking for guidance to help me learn since I'm new to PHP.

I've added the ability to upload images for a post in a simple posts app. I'm trying to use the validation code from W3schools, inserted just below `$image_temp   = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];` below

```
    <?php include 'inc/header.php';
        // Check for submit
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            // Get form data
            $title  = $_POST['title'];
            $body   = $_POST['body'];
            $author = $_POST['author'];
            $tags = $_POST['tags'];
    
            $image        = $_FILES['image']['name'];
            $image_temp   = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

$target_dir = "img/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
      if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
      } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
      }
    }
    
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
      echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 500000) {
      echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    
    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
      echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
      $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    
    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
      echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
      } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
      }
    }
    
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO posts(title, body, author, tags, image) VALUES (:title, :body, :author, :tags, :image)';
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(['title' => $title, 'body' => $body, 'author' => $author, 'tags' => $tags, 'image' => $image]);
            flash('post_added', 'Post added successfully', 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show');
        }
    ?>
```

The code seems to work - however - the post submits even if there are image errors. How do I fix that?

I also want to allow posts without images (is that a bad thing?).  I have a function that checks if an image is present - if not it will display a placeholder.

Any guidance to help me understand this is gratefully received.

Comment: I had the same issue when first working with file uploads. I got around this by adding a die() or exit() after each error so PHP would stop executing the rest of the code if an issue was found along the way.

If you leave just echo, it'll simply echo out the message and continue on it's merry way to execute the next statements. You can try wrap the messages like this instead: die('message describing error'); This way a message is still relayed and the code doesn't continue to upload the image when there are errors present.

Comment: That's a good idea - got me thinking too - I might be able to put a flash message in there before the exit or die statement.  I'll give that a try tonight when I get home.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I have it working to the point it won't create the post - but, it places the error message at the top of the page and leaves the rest of the page blank.  Still working through this one.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up joining each check with an `elseif` - this meant having the query twice in the flow - once after allowing the post if a file wasn't uploaded and once after all the checks were done.  Not sure if this is the best way, but it works.

```
 $target_dir = "img/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
        $uploadOk = 1;
        $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        // Check if image file exists, and allow
        if (!(file_exists($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))){
            // Create the post
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO posts(title, body, author, tags, status, image) VALUES (:title, :body, :author, :tags, :status, :image)';
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute(['title' => $title, 'body' => $body, 'author' => $author, 'tags' => $tags, 'status' => $status, 'image' => $image]);
            flash('post_added', 'Post added successfully', 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show');
        } elseif (file_exists($target_file)) {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show text-center'>Sorry, file already exists.<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
      <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        } elseif ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 500000) {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show text-center'>Sorry, your file is too large.<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
      <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        } elseif($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
            && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
            echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show text-center'>Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
      <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        } elseif ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "";

        // if everything is ok, try to upload file
        } else {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
                echo "<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show text-center'>The file ". basename( $_FILES["image"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
      <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span></button></div>";

                // Create the post
                $sql = 'INSERT INTO posts(title, body, author, tags, status, image) VALUES (:title, :body, :author, :tags, :status, :image)';
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $stmt->execute(['title' => $title, 'body' => $body, 'author' => $author, 'tags' => $tags, 'status' => $status, 'image' => $image]);
                flash('post_added', 'Post added successfully', 'alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show');
            }
        }
```